# awk escape plus '+' sign

Tags: awk

Trying to find matching lines from 'wg' (wireguard) command output where public_keys are given which can have forward slash and/or '+' (plus) signs.

So I try: `awk '$0~v' v="$peer" RS=`

```
# peer="KDyRQuyvygoAamIMB/6RKWxyb7urysDCldIVbIM5DRQ="
# echo $peer
KDyRQuyvygoAamIMB/6RKWxyb7urysDCldIVbIM5DRQ=
# wg | awk '$0~v' v="$peer" RS=
peer: KDyRQuyvygoAamIMB/6RKWxyb7urysDCldIVbIM5DRQ=
  preshared key: (hidden)
  endpoint: 1.2.3.4:44529
  allowed ips: 10.33.17.0/24
  latest handshake: 41 seconds ago
  transfer: 3.64 KiB received, 7.43 KiB sent
  persistent keepalive: every 25 seconds
```

While the above works with forward slashes, the following does not work if public_keys/strings contain plus '+' sign:

```
# peer="JeMdiPUksJRpc+LNGbG9Nw/ubVSzj/eFGgrEVwp0z2w="
# echo $peer
JeMdiPUksJRpc+LNGbG9Nw/ubVSzj/eFGgrEVwp0z2w=
# wg | awk '$0~v' v="$peer" RS=
#
```

How would a match work in this situation?

Comment: BTW, `echo $peer` is itself buggy -- it should always be `echo "$peer"`. See [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `regex` match, use plain string search using `index` using *any one* of following options:

```bash
# if $peer needs to be matched at the start position of 2nd field
wg | awk -v v="$peer" -v RS= '$1=="peer:" && index($2, v) == 1'

# or if $peer needs to be full matched with 2nd field
wg | awk -v v="$peer" -v RS= '$1=="peer:" $2 == v'
```

This would match value of `$peer` at the start of `$2` when `$1` is `peer:`.

Comment: `jot -w 'peer: %9lX' - 47153691294923 47153691294923 | mawk -v ___='2AE2D304FCCB' -v RS= --  'END { print NR,NF, $0 } $1=="peer:" $2 == ___ { print "matched" } ' 1 2 peer: 2AE2D304FCCB` :: `nawk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 END { print NR,NF, $0 } $1=="peer:" $2 >>>  == <<< 
nawk: bailing out at source line 1` ::: `gawk -v ___='2AE2D304FCCB' -v RS= 'END { print NR,NF, $0 } $1=="peer:" $2 == ___ { print "matched" } ' gawk: cmd. line:1: END { print NR,NF, $0 } $1=="peer:" $2 == ___ { print "matched" } gawk: cmd. line:1:                            ^ syntax error`

Comment: long story short - `gawk` and `nawk` both failed out, while `mawk` quietly accepted it but failed to match it.

Answer (score 0):

To do this robustly avoiding false matches with regexp metachars or substrings you should use full string matching on lines:

```
wg | awk -v v="$peer" '$0 == ("peer: " v){f=1} f'
```

or fields:

```
wg | awk -v v="$peer" -v RS= '$2 == v'
```